# Removing background mask for K -Means clustering/ in Python or C++

Tags: python, c++, k-means

I am trying to classify an image using K-Means clustering Python library. However, included in the image is a black (masked) background which i require being removed before clustering as it affects the output results.I wish to remove the black background class or cluster from the image output using k-means.
I have tried looking online for solutions however i have so far failed to get anything suitable. Is anyone aware of any solutions available for removing an unwanted specific class/cluster in K -means cluster algorithm using Python Library or C++. Below is the K- means code that i'm currently implementing in python, and wish to adapt.

```
labels = _utils.clusterFeatureVectors(featureVectors, k_clusters)
_utils.printClassifiedImage(labels, k_clusters, img, outfile, greyOutput)
```

Comment: How is "included in the image is a black (masked) background" encoded, or represented (probably nd array...)? is it another layer in your image array? How are you reading the image? Chanels, etc... Links to libraries you are using? -> that _utils usage seems akward, is it yours? Where would the rest of the code be then...?

Answer (score 0):

I found this codes by mistake and I think is useful.

```py
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "#000000") #black color will be removed
```

For more informatiosn you can look here:
https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/wm+attributes